# How to join the tables in codeigniter?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, join

I am trying to join two tables in codeigniter, in these two tables one table contain business idea and in another table it contains vote on each idea. I have given idea_id is foreign key in user_votes table. I need to join these two tables and shows all idea & their respective likes and dislikes. One more thing in user_votes table I have taken one column user_action and I set the flag 1 as like and 2 as dislike. please have any solution how to join in this case.
**here is my table structure**
[image]

This is my voting table

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$results = 
    $this->db
    ->select('business_ideas.*,
        SUM(case when user_votes.user_action=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as likes,
        SUM(case when user_votes.user_action=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as dislikes
    ')
    ->from('business_ideas')
    ->join('user_votes', 'business_ideas.idea_id = user_votes.idea_id', 'inner')
    ->group_by('business_idea.idea_id')
    ->get();
```

Not tested.

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->db->select('business_ideas.*, user_votes.user_action');
$this->db->from('business_ideas');
$this->db->join('user_votes', 'business_ideas.id = user_votes.idea_id', 'inner');
$result = $this->db->get();
$finalOutput = $result->row_array();
print_r($finalOutput);
```

But it need some correction in your table structure in table "business_ideas", your primary key should be 'id' instead of 'idea_id'.

Comment: Why would the name of the primary key matter?

Comment: Its not compulsory buddy, but good coding practise needs it to be modified. But rest is upto you.